# Can I get Source code from dist file in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]
I lost my code which was created by Vue.js but I built it before so i have dist file .can this help me to get my source code ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you built it with source maps? If so, you should see `.map` files inside the `dist/js` folder.

If you built with source maps, you can serve this dist folder and check your code at browsers dev tools.

Comment: @mumumik .. please can you explain more?

Comment: @NadinGomaa do you see files with `.map` extension inside your `dist/js` folder? If so, you can use a npm library such as `http-server` to serve this application locally and see the code through your browser's developer tools.